# Difference between DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value And DropDownList.SelectedValue (ASP.NET)

Tags: drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I'm getting an error when `SelctedIndexChanged`, When the value change he gives me the previous selected value and not the new selected value.

What's the problem here.

And what's the difference between

```
DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value 
DropDownList.SelectedValue
```

Answer (score 6):

**SelectedValues** returns the Value of the selecteditem or "" if there is none.

**SelectedItem** returns the selected item. **SelectedItem.Value** return the .Value
of the SelectedItem. **SelectedItem.Value** will throw an error if there is no
selected item, because **SelectedItem** will return null, and .Value of null
will throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

selectedValue retrns the order no of listitem of dropdown and nothing is selected then it returns "" and Selecteditem.text return text of selected item and selecteditem.value also returns order no but if not selected then throw an error