# How to get the selected value from aspx drop down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using following code to show the drop down in my aspx page and the data loaded in the dropdown are occurring by `SqlDatasource4`

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListnew" runat="server" 
     CssClass="ddlb" Width="210px" Height="30px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" 
     DataTextField="OrderPeriod" DataValueField="OrderPeriodID">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

When i tried to access the Dropdown data in my `C#` file by following code:

```
string data = DropDownListnew.Text;
```

It prints the no of selected value, I want to store selected value in data string. How should i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it by;

```
string data = DropDownListnew.SelectedValue; // property not .Text property
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string data = DropDownListnew.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

One more property to get selected value from DropDownList.

```
string data = DropDownListnew.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: While this will work, its probably preferable to use SelectedValue. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944036/difference-between-dropdownlist-selecteditem-value-and-dropdownlist-selectedvalu) stackoverflow question.